# Load URL in WebView without http://www prefix

Tags: java, android, url

Please, don't mark this as duplicate.

If you call `WebView.loadUrl` with a parameter like `google.com`, it will fail. So, as other similar questions suggest, you do something like this:

```
if(!url.startsWith("www."))
    url = "www." + url;
if(!url.startsWith("http://") && !url.startsWith("https://"))
    url = "http://" + url;
webView.loadUrl(url);
```

But, in case of, say, `play.google.com`, it will try to load `http://www.play.google.com` and fail.

If you don't add `www`, some websites will still fail, for example, `eurobeat-prime.com` won't work without `www` prefix.

How can I process such links? (Because modern browsers do)

Comment: "How can I process such links?" -- delete your first `if`. Put the `https://` scheme on the domain name and go from there.

Comment: @CommonsWare, that website really won't work without www. Also, https:// won't work with http only websites (for example, http://info.cern.ch)

Comment: Maybe you want to read URL class reference. https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URL

Comment: You can use your favorite HTTP client API (e.g., OkHttp) to issue a bunch of `HEAD` requests to try to identify a URL to use.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you need to append `www`

You can directly use this instead.

```
if(!url.startsWith("http://") && !url.startsWith("https://"))
    url = "http://" + url;
webView.loadUrl(url);
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer, I think I'll leave it that way (if I won't find a better alternative). Some websites really don't have redirect to www, like the one that I posted. Chrome opens it correctly, but loadUrl("http:// eurobeat-prime.com") won't work (I tested it)

Comment: Don't use http://, use https:// the latest version of the Chrome browser which is the webView's underlying browser will not allow unencrypted (ie not https://) traffic.

Answer (score 0):

if you run across a URL that won't open in the webView directly, you can usually succeed in opening it in an external browser window:

```
protected void handleExternalDeviceActivity(String url) {
    //pass this special URL to an external activity (outside of the app)
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
    startActivity(intent);
}
```